# What will be the url to show all content type posts?

Tags: nodes

OK i have created a content type. But what will be the url that will show the list of all posts in specific content type?
Basically I want to make a link or a menu item that will show all posts in specific content type but off course paginated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to a URL that every user with permission to view published nodes would see, then a Drupal fresh installation doesn't have such a URL. There is a URL that only users with the permission to administer nodes can see, and that shows the list of all the nodes, which can then be filtered by content type and other criteria.

[image: screenshot of the page at admin/content]

For a URL that is accessible to anybody, you need to use a third-party module, such as Views, as Nigel already reported. Using [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), you can create a page that is very similar to the page to administer content, but that is visible to any user having less restrictive permissions. Being a view, it can be customized as every view; in particular, the filter criteria are the usual exposed filters used by Views.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

You will have to use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to create list filtering for a specific content type.

The Views module provides a flexible method for Drupal site designers to control how lists and tables of content (nodes in Views 1, almost anything in Views 2) are presented. Traditionally, Drupal has hard-coded most of this, particularly in how taxonomy and tracker lists are formatted.

This tool is essentially a smart query builder that, given enough information, can build the proper query, execute it, and display the results. It has four modes, plus a special mode, and provides an impressive amount of functionality from these modes.

Among other things, Views can be used to generate reports, create summaries, and display collections of images and other content.
You need Views if:

1. You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort
   it differently.
2. You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you want to
   sort it differently; for example, alphabetically.
3. You use /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain
   type.
4. You like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display
   articles the way you like.

Views can do a lot more than that, but those are some of the obvious uses of Views.

Here is a series of [awesome tutorials on Views](http://nodeone.se/blogg/learn-views-with-nodeone-part-1-overview)  (**I am not affiliated with the author(s)**)